Replace HostName on ssh config from bash
I'm trying to replace the IP stored on HostName of the following ssh config matching the Host above it.
Host my_host_1
    User user
    HostName 1.0.3.4
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /some/path
    ProxyCommand ssh user@something -W %h:%p

Host my_host_2
    User user
    HostName 1.0.3.5
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /some/path
    ProxyCommand ssh user@something -W %h:%p

For example

Replace Host of my_host_2 by 4.3.2.1.

I tried to isolate the IP with the following regex (which is working).
/(?<=HostName )\d.\d.\d.\d/gm

But I'm not able to look behind on several lines to make a condition on the Host value.

And what did you try? WHere did you got stuck?

I just tried to cat + grep to find the correct regex but I was not able to isolate the IP for now. Once correct regex is found, I think we can use it with a sed.

Please post what have you tried and not put in the comment section.

I've updated the question.
It's different @0stone0 because there is a "double" look behind on multi lines.

You could use proper ssh config syntax aware editors like https://github.com/trntv/sshed

I wanted something without any special configuration and actually, with this tool, I did not see the "update" of an existing configuration. Only remove/add which is not what I'm looking for.
Thank you anyway for the suggestion @Inian

Updating a file is trivial - foo file > tmp && mv tmp file for any given command foo.  There are also command-specific options to avoid manually creating the tmp file but a glance at the man page for any tool will tell you how to do that. So, most answers won't address that as it's generally irrelevant clutter.

sed '/Host my_host_2/,/Host / s/HostName .*/HostName 9.9.9.9/' /path/to/file

Will replace HostName .* with HostName 9.9.9.9 in the first occurrence ofter Host my_host_2

Add the -i option if you want to edit it in-place:
sed -i '/Host my_host_2/,/Host / s/HostName .*/HostName 9.9.9.9/' ~/.ssh/config

For eg MacOS you'll need something else as explained here.

I'm not able to make it work. Could you add the whole command line to update it on file ~/.ssh/config please?
I'm missing something so be able to test it.
Thank you for your answer anyway!

Added an example to replace in-place. Keep in mind that won't work on Eg MacOs.

AhAh, I'm on MacOs. That's why it's not working because I tried exactly the same command line as you did.

Then you'll need to use something like sed -i.bak 'filter' ~/.ssh/config but please read the shared link to get the context as well ;)

Bash killer ❤️
Thank you!

It depends on what tool you want to use edit the file. I would recommend ed:
printf '%s\n' \ 
  "/Host my_name_2/" \
  "/HostName/" \
  "s/\(.*HostName \).*/\1 4.3.2.1/" \
  "wq" | ed .ssh/config

This works by doing the following:

Jumping to the line containing Host my_name_2
Jumping to the next line containing HostName
Replacing the entire line with the directive name plus the desired IP address
Saving and exiting.

The substitution preserves whatever indentation preceded HostName, as well as assuming that nothing on the line after the name of the option needs to be preserved. I don't consider actually matching the old HostName value to be important.

Something like this
s/(Host\s+my_host_2.+HostName )\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+/$1 4.3.2.1/gm

I tried the first part on regex101 and there is on match for /(Host\s+my_host_2.+HostName )\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+/gm

Since this has a bash tag, one approach using bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

to_change=0
replacement=4.3.2.1
target_block_name='Host my_host_2'

while IFS= read -r line; do
   [[ "$line" == "$target_block_name" ]] && {
   to_change=1
  }
  if ((to_change)) && [[ "$line" == *'HostName'* ]]; then
    line="${line% *} $replacement" &&
    to_change=0
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < .ssh/config


• To edit/change the file redirect the the new output to a new file change the last line to.
done < .ssh/config > output.txt && mv -v output.txt .ssh/config


Another ed approach
#!/bin/sh

ed -s .ssh/config <<'EOF'
  /Host my_host_2/;/HostName/kx
  'xs/\([^ ]*\)$/4.3.2.1/
  ,p
  Q
EOF


In-one-line
printf '%s\n' '/Host my_host_2/;/HostName/kx' "'xs/\([^ ]*\)$/4.3.2.1/" ,p Q | ed -s .ssh/config


• Change the Q to w or wq if in place editing is required.
• Remove the ,p to silence the output to stdout

Using perl :
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/(Host my_host_2.*?HostName) \S+/$1 4.3.2.1/s' config


Using any awk:
$ awk '
    /^Host/ { name = $2 }
    (name == "my_host_2") && ($1 == "HostName") {
         sub(/[^ ]+$/, "")
         $0 = $0 "4.3.2.1"
    }
    { print }
' file
Host my_host_1
    User user
    HostName 1.0.3.4
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /some/path
    ProxyCommand ssh user@something -W %h:%p

Host my_host_2
    User user
    HostName 4.3.2.1
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /some/path
    ProxyCommand ssh user@something -W %h:%p

